# Exception System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown.in linesolve ilnumerics

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I have a problem with linesolve in ilnumerics. Here are the code:

```
A = A_damped; // (6691x3000) array
D = d_damped; // array size 6691

ILArray<double> AA = A; // AA matrix (3000x6691) so should be transposed
 AA = AA.T;
ILArray<double> BB = D; // matrix (6691 x 1) 
ILArray<double> CC = ILMath.linsolve(AA, BB);
```

and I got the following notifications :

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

is there anyone here has a clue?

Comment: Are you getting this error reliably, or does it only happen once in a while? Have you checked how much memory your application is using? Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit? Did you specify `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the suggestions by @Luaan make sure that your problem size is in a reasonable range. Your matrix consumes ~153MB. Linsolve needs some temporary memory as well. More is needed for temporary arrays during general computations. As a very rough rule of thumb, your problem size should not exceed 1 third of the **RAM** available to your application. This is hard to determine reliably, since there are always other processes running on the system, consuming memory as well ...

- The first thing when you encounter OOM issues is to target 64bit.
- Make sure to use [the latest version](http://ilnumerics.net/download.html) of ILNumerics. As of today this is 4.10.
- If this does not reliably remove the OOMs you will have to decrease your problem size or use distributed memory instead.

Comment: Thanks Haymo and Luaan, it solves my problem. I run the application in 64 bit, and then I checked the configuration of the project, I change all target platform to anyCPU instead of 86x (previously).

Comment: Why AnyCPU? If you want to make sure that it is run in 64 bit you should target x64 explicitly. Btw, the way to say 'thanks' on SO is to upvote and mark as answered.

Comment: I need to test the application in other PC (sometimes in 32bit) so I need the application to run smoothly in other PC. I'm sorry I have no enough reputation to upvote your answer. :)  btw Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the correct answer. This will help others.